# how to calculate a function in prolog?

Tags: function, prolog, max

We have to find a function in prolog Q(a,b,n) with a < b and with the following way:
Q(a, b, n) = max { k ∈ N | b ^ k  - a ^ k < = n}

here is the my code but it is always giving me a "no"

```
qs(A,B,N,R,C) :- R>N, R is B^C-A^C.
qs(A,B,N,R,C) :- A<B, C1 is C, R is B^C1-A^C1, C1 is C+1, R=<N, qs(A,B,N,R,C1).
qs(A,B,N,R) :- A<B, C is 0, qs(A,B,N,R,C).
```

For example if I had Q(2,3,18) the output should be 2.

Comment: I am getting an "instantiation error" for `qs(2,3,18,R)`. You really should tell the actual definition of that function. We can only guess.

Comment: And `qs(3,2,1,R).` fails. Right?

Comment: i thought the definition was there..there was something wrong with the post so i edited it again and here you go ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qs(A, B, N, R) :-
   A < B,
   once((
      length(_,K),
      B^K - A^K > N
   )),
   R is K-1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe prolog uses ** for exponentiation, not ^ (assuming that's what you want to do).

Comment: Actually, both works. (^)/2 has the advantage of producing integer values if both operands are integers, whereas (**)/2 always produces a float.